# Netty add httprequest to server handling

Tags: java, netty, microservices

I use microservice architecture in my project. And for interservice communication I use message queue [NATS](http://nats.io/). I wrote a gateway, that handle all http requests and put it to queue. All end point services are subscribed to this queue.

At endpoint services I use [Xitrum](http://xitrum-framework.github.io/) based on Netty IO. When I get request from queue, I deserialise it to FullHttpRequest. But I don't know how to send it to my netty server, that can handle it  according to business logic   (without using external httpclient, for example, that can send it to localhost)

Is there any possibility to send FullHttpRequest instance to netty server (listening localhost:8000) using netty api? Or may be another solution. What is the common approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the netty examples which has everything you need:
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop

Comment: So you suggest to create new instance of bootstrap server and handle NATS request with this instance and don't use Xitrum Server directly?